# Best practice of adding SupportMapFragment (its own activity or child of another fragment)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I've successfully embedded a `SupportMapFragment` into an activity and also as a child of another fragment, i've added it statically in the XML and dynamically using code.

I've no problem regarding that, my question is .. which is better to do ? should the map be in it's own activity ? or add it in a fragment ?

Problems i had with adding `SupportMapFragment` as child fragment is when replacing that fragment it's kinda slow and has some blinking issues.

So should i take into consideration -in the future- not to put maps in a `ViewPager` or Tabbed view
or any other element that would cause the map to be swiped in and out quickly ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Map Fragment is unfortunately quite slow.
The only thing you can do to enhance the creation time is to call MapsInitializer.initialize(Context) in the Application onCreate in order to have some of the map components already initialized before creating the Fragment.
Another thing you might do is using directly the MapView taking care of the lifecycle yourself in order to not destroy/recreate it every time

Comment: Both suggestions could be quite expensive if the user decides not to navigate to the tab or page that has the map ...

Comment: Yes of course that's true. I recommend doing that only if the map is a fundamental part of the app.